# PostgreSQL Insertion is taking very long time

Tags: postgresql, jdbctemplate

I am using jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query, inputList) for batch insertion in postgresql.
It is taking ~25 mins for 5000 records( batcheSize is 700 records). Same batch is taking ~2 min in db2.
What should i do to improve performance?

Comment: Why tag `SQL Server` when your question is on `PostgreSQL` ?

Comment: Do you see any other activity on your database or this table? Use pg_stat_activity. It doesn't look like a performance issue, any database can do this in 25 minutes. You could do it manually...

Comment: Lots of things to check, indexes slow down inserts, table bloat, buffer size etc. What are the config diffs between db's , are you on different hardware ?

Comment: ... and what does your code look like?

Comment: Put some code for everyone to see and provide feedback on the code.
The implementation can also have problem which can't be caught with this post.